# Discrepancy between ReplaceList and ReplaceAll?

Tags: replacement

Consider the following

```
ClearAll[eqv, not, neqv, p, q, r]
ReplaceAll[eqv[neqv[p, q], r], neqv[p_, q_] :> not[eqv[p, q]]]
```

> `eqv[not[eqv[p, q]], r]`

According to the documentation, I should expect `ReplaceList` to return (at least) this result in a list, but, instead, I am surprised to get an empty list:

```
ClearAll[eqv, not, neqv, p, q, r]
ReplaceList[eqv[neqv[p, q], r], neqv[p_, q_] :> not[eqv[p, q]]]
```

> `{}`

Again, according to the documentation, `ReplaceList` thinks there is no transformation possible, but `ReplaceAll` found one. I didn't see any indication that `ReplaceList` could be expected to return the empty list under any other circumstances.

This is important because in some deeper and more complicated programs, I need to scan all alternative replacements, but I now fear I can't trust `ReplaceList`.

Mathematica 11.3.0.0
Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is within the documented design of these functions.

> `ReplaceList[expr,rules]` attempts to transform the **entire expression *expr*** by applying a rule or list of rules in all possible ways, and returns a list of the results obtained.
>
> `ReplaceAll[expr,rules]` applies a rule or list of rules in an attempt to transform **each subpart** of an expression expr.

Perhaps a simpler example clarifies things:

```
In[3]:= ReplaceList[{1, 2, 3, 4}, x_Integer :> x^2]

Out[3]= {}

In[4]:= ReplaceAll[{1, 2, 3, 4}, x_Integer :> x^2]

Out[4]= {1, 4, 9, 16}
```

Comment: Sure enough, `ReplaceList[neqvRule] /@ eqv[neqv[p, q], r]`, mapping instead of applying, reveals what I expected `eqv[{not[eqv[neqv[p], neqv[q]]], not[eqv[p, q]]}, {}]`.